# Hive - hourly window averages

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, psql, hiveql

I have data like this in a Hive table:

```
+-------------------+-------+---------+--------+
| _c0               | name  | value0  | value1 |
+-------------------+-------+---------+--------+
| 2015-10-07 13:01  | john  | 10.0    | 100    |
| 2015-10-07 13:20  | john  | 20.0    | 200    |
| 2015-10-07 13:41  | john  | 15.0    | 300    |
| 2015-10-07 14:00  | john  | 30.0    | 300    |
| 2015-10-07 14:20  | john  | 60.0    | 200    |
| 2015-10-07 14:40  | john  | 30.0    | 400    |
```

I need to get hourly averages.

```
| 2015-10-07 13:00  | john  | 15.0    | 200    |
| 2015-10-07 14:00  | john  | 40.0    | 300    |
```

I have an idea about doing it using a `partition`/`over` clause in psql but I'm not sure how to do this in Hive. An idea would be to split datetime into date and hour (e.g."2015-10-07 13") and use a group by and avg function, but that is probably not the best way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it the way you suggested to do it.  If you are just wanting the average by date and hour (and name probably), partitioning and using an over clause is not necessary.

**Query**:

```
select date, hour, name, avg(value0) avg0, avg(value1) avg1
from (
  select split(_c0, ' ')[0] date
    , split(split(_c0, ' ')[1], '\\:')[0] hour
    , name
    , value0
    , value1
  from db.table ) x
group by date, hour, name
```